# Get datetime field in specific format

Tags: sql-server, date-format, sqldatetime

```
( SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.EndDate,101))[end]
```

will return date as `06/17/2013` and

```
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.StartDate) )[start]
```

will return date as `Jun 17 2013  2:00PM` and I need date in the following format  `06/17/2013 2:00 PM("/" is important)` . Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.EndDate,101) +' ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.EndDate,8)) AS end
```

[More Here](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.EndDate,101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),it.EndDate),7) AS [END]
```

The same for it.StartDate